# MSGraph - device query with $filter

Tags: filter, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Have made an application in AAD with Delegate access and made a PS to connect to Graph and run a query using this format:

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?$filter=DeviceId eq '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'"

$method = "GET"

$query = Invoke-WebRequest -Method $method -Uri $uri -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"} -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop

Write-Host $query
```

$query instead of giving me only the result for the $filter I've applied, it returns all devices in my Tenant.
I'm using the command as Microsoft intended so not sure why doesn't work.

My end-goal is to update 'DevicePhysicalId' only for the device I have the deviceId of but unfortunately I can's search in MSGraph using deviceId, have to use objectId instead. So either $filter works or I need a solution to work out with the list of all devices I have as result.

Thanks,

Stef

Comment: interesting, if I try the same query on https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer it works properly. I'm baffled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use PowerShell backtick character before `$filter` clause.

Without backtick character PowerShell works with `$filter` as with property

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?$filter=DeviceId eq '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'"
Write-Host $uri
```

Uri is without `$filter` clause

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?=DeviceId eq '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'`

With backtick character

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?`$filter=DeviceId eq '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'"
Write-Host $uri
```

Uri is

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?$filter=DeviceId eq '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'`

Comment: OMG I love you so much, that was it! It just needed the backtick character. I had no idea. Sir you made my day!